# MS Access OleDB does not return any row

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I'm using this code to return data to my app:

```
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionStringAccess());
            string cSQL = "SELECT Cracha, Data_Hora, Terminal, Entrada_Saida, Situacao, Tipo, Divergencia, SaiuMarcacao, Justificativa, IDMarcacao, PIS, NSR FROM Marcacao";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = cSQL;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();
            return dr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

But nothing is returned. My db has one million records.

If I access the db using Dataset/Table adapters, the data is showed normally, but in code nothing returns;

Here is the connection string returned by my method GetConnectionStringAccess():

```
       "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\CCBM\\Ponto Dimep\\BM\\DIMEP.Mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxx"
```

Here is my method to get the application connectionstring from app.config:

```
    public static string GetConnectionStringAccess()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImportaAccess.Properties.Settings.PontoAccessBM"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

In app.config, this is the connectionstring key:

```
    <add name="ImportaAccess.Properties.Settings.PontoAccessBM" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\CCBM\Ponto Dimep\BM\DIMEP.Mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=obdI109j"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Why my code does not return any row using this code and return all the rows if I run the tableAdapter.Fill method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read from your datareader into an object, before you close the connection. Like:

```
List<object> x = new List<>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    x.Add(<your stuff>); // add as appropriate
}
```

then return the List (or whatever you use) instead of returning the datareader

Answer (score 0):

Because your DataReader is a pointer and you are closing before the return.

Try to retrieve the data before the DataReader closes using a data table
Like this:

```
 try
    {  
       DataTable Tbl = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionStringAccess());
        string cSQL = "SELECT Cracha, Data_Hora, Terminal, Entrada_Saida, Situacao, Tipo, Divergencia, SaiuMarcacao, Justificativa, IDMarcacao, PIS, NSR FROM Marcacao";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = cSQL;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Tbl.Load(rd,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        conn.Close();
        return Tbl;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```